# Getting error "The name 'Configuration' does not exist in the current context"

Tags: c#, configurationmanager

I am using Visual Studio 2013 with .NET Framework 4.5.

I have included the `System.Configuration` as a reference in the project.

I have also included a using statement in the class as such:

```
using System.Configuration;
```

However, the following line still gives me the above subject error. How do I get rid of the error?

```
using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["WarrantySqlConnection"].ToString()))
```

The compile time error is on the `ConfigurationManager` word.

Comment: Try saving the entire solution (both project and `.cs` file), close Visual Studio, and open it again. Check that `System.Configuration` is indeed in the References of the same project.

Comment: Let us know what the problem was when you resolve it, I'm curious

Comment: I had it in the WRONG project within my solution. After adding the reference, I then needed to obviously add the using statement and that solved it.

Answer (score 3):

Try remove and re-add the reference to the assembly `System.Configuration.dll` , by right-clicking on the References, choose add reference and then find `System.Configuration`.
After you add a reference to the dll if you have still problem save and close your Visual Studio and restart it.

Comment: Also he can do clean/rebuild solution.

Answer (score 3):

In .Net Core 6.0 or 7.0. You have to write the builder.Services in Program.cs class as shown below images
[image: The class Name is Program.cs]

If you have question let me know

Answer (score -1):

Right click on project, add, reference.
Find System.Configuration and click on it.

[image]