# Error at define Sql Connection in winform c#

Tags: c#, winforms, connection-string, sqlconnection, sqlcommand

I write this code in my app.config:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<configuration>
    <startup> 
        <supportedRuntime version="v4.0" sku=".NETFramework,Version=v4.5" />

    </startup>
  <connectionStrings>
    <add name="localservice" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient"
          connectionString="Data Source=GROOT\SQL;Initial Catalog=localservice;Integrated Security=True" />
  </connectionStrings>

</configuration>
```

My c# code is :

```
using System;
using System.Configuration;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.Data;
using System.Data.SqlClient;

       private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

            int radius = 10;

            SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["miztahrirtest2DB"].ToString());
            SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("insert into vendor (username,password,lenght,width,radius,category) values (@username,@password,@lenght,@width,@radius,@category);SELECT SCOPE_IDENTITY()", con);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("username", textBox1.Text);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("password", textBox2.Text);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("lenght", Convert.ToInt32(textBox3.Text));
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("width", Convert.ToInt32(textBox4.Text));
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("radius", radius);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("category", comboBox1.Text);
            con.Open();
            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
            //Int32 classid = Convert.ToInt32(cmd.ExecuteScalar());
            con.Close();

        }
    }
}
```

But there is an error on this line:

```
SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["miztahrirtest2DB"].ToString());
```

and said :

> Error 1   The type or namespace name 'ConfigurationManager' does not
>   exist in the namespace 'System.Configuration' (are you missing an
>   assembly reference?)  D:\visual studio
>   project\Project\LocalService1\LocalService1\signup.cs 35  72  LocalService1

Comment: It seems the error is self describing. You should add a reference to `System.Configuration.dll` first.

Comment: Why not retrieve the connection string directly from `Settings.Default.WhatsYourConnectionName`?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Getting error "The name 'Configuration' does not exist in the current context](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32121383/getting-error-the-name-configuration-does-not-exist-in-the-current-context)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should add a reference `System.Configuration.dll` to your project.

Right click on project, from `Add` menu, click `Reference...` and from the dialog, search for `System.Configuration.dll` and click the checkbox to check it, then click ok.

- If you are using VS2010 you can't search and you should select the dll from .Net tab
- If you are using VS2013 you can select Assemblies -> Framework node.

Answer (score 0):

```
SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["localservice"].ToString());
```

You are given different name in web.config,But in C# you are given different name in **ConnectionStrings["localservice"]**